# How to get an variable, as result of an api request, into a text field?

Tags: flutter

I am able to make an api request and in my console I get the result of the api request correctly. Now I want to use the result and show some data on the screen. The problem is that I do not know how to attach the api result to a variable that can be used in the screen.

When making a new flutter project and using the "Fetch data from the internet" document then I am able to show things from the api result on the screen. Then after using this code and integrate it into my app it is not working. It only shows the "return CircularProgressIndicator();" in the screen.

```
Future<Result> fetchPost() async {
  final response = await http.get(
      'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?    placeid=ChIJYRUMU1blxkcRG7zLfuAzM9I&key=sorry not showing my key in here');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the call to the server was successful, parse the JSON
    print('All Good! This link returned status code   ${response.statusCode}');
    debugPrint(response.body);

    return Result.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));

  } else {
    // If that call was not successful, throw an error.
    throw Exception('Failed to load post');
  }
}

// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final result = resultFromJson(jsonString);

Result resultFromJson(String str) =>     Result.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String resultToJson(Result data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Result {
  List<dynamic> htmlAttributions;
  ResultClass result;

  Result({
    this.htmlAttributions,
    this.result,
  });

  factory Result.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => new Result(
        htmlAttributions:
            new List<dynamic>.from(json["html_attributions"].map((x)  => x)),
        result: ResultClass.fromJson(json["result"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "html_attributions":
            new List<dynamic>.from(htmlAttributions.map((x) => x)),
        "result": result.toJson(),
      };
}

//THEN ALL THE CLASSES TO GET THE DATA. debugPrint(response.body);     SHOWS THE WANTED DATA IN THE CONSOLE. THIS PART IS WORKING.
//IN THE CODE BELOW THE FutureBuilder WILL RUN BUT return   CircularProgressIndicator(); IS THE PART THAT IS EXECUTED.


class Home extends StatelessWidget {

  final Future<Result> result;

  Home({Key key, this.result}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Home"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraint) {
              return new Image.asset(
                'assets/images/Sprokkelbos logo 621x621.jpg',
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
              );
            }),
          ),
          /*
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: FutureBuilder<Result>(
            future: result,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return     Text(snapshot.data.result.openingHours.periods[1].close.time);
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text("${snapshot.error}");
              }
              // By default, show a loading spinner
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
            ),
          ),
          */

          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: _buildText(
                //text: 'flex: 1', color: Colors.white, textColor: Colors.black),
                text: ('TEST: ')),
          ),
```

Text(snapshot.data.result.openingHours.periods[1].close.time); should give me a value like it is in the api result. It is e.g. 1700 what stands for the closing time (hhmm) of the shop. Why do I get the return CircularProgressIndicator(); instead?

The flutter document example that works fine has only one  dart file (just main.dart). In my app the code is in a second screen (not in main.dart).

When I replace return CircularProgressIndicator(); with return Text('snapshot.hasData? ${snapshot.hasData} and snapshot.hasError? ${snapshot.hasError}'); then I see that both are false. Why is notting available in the snapshot?

Comment: What happens when you put `return CircularProgressIndicator();` inside an else block

Comment: Where are you instantiating the `Home` widget? Are you sure you passed in the result future?

Comment: @rmtmckenzie: In main.dart I am calling home.dart in a build widget. For testing I made a button in home.dart to call the fetchpost. Also because i do not know (jet) how to activate this when opening home.dart. I do not fully understand what you mean with your second question. Is my lack of knowledge....

Comment: @AlexLushiku: makes no difference. The IF and the ELSE IF are not fulfilled, because of the snapshot condition I think. It looks like snapshot has no data but also no error.

Comment: Is there anybody who can help me?